# Templating system scoping issue

Tags: php, templates, scope

I'm trying to whip up a skeleton View system in PHP, but I can't figure out how to get embedded views to receive their parent's variables. For example:

**View Class**

```
class View
{
    private $_vars=array();
    private $_file;

    public function __construct($file)
    {
        $this->_file='views/'.$file.'.php';
    }

    public function set($var, $value=null)
    {
        if (is_array($var))
        {
            $this->_vars=array_merge($var, $this->_vars);
        }
        else
            $this->_vars[$var]=$value;

        return $this;
    }

    public function output()
    {
        if (count($this->_vars))
            extract($this->_vars,  EXTR_REFS);
        require($this->_file);
        exit;
    }

    public static function factory($file)
    {
        return new self($file);
    }
}
```

**test.php (top level view)**

```
<html>
    <body>
        Hey <?=$name?>! This is <?=$adj?>!
        <?=View::factory('embed')->output()?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**embed.php (embedded in test.php**

```
<html>
    <body>
        Hey <?=$name?>! This is an embedded view file!!
    </body>
</html>
```

**Code:**

```
$vars=array(
    'name' => 'ryan',
    'adj' => 'cool'
);
View::factory('test')->set($vars)->output();
```

**Output:**

```
Hey ryan! This is cool! Hey [error for $name not being defined] 
this is an embedded view file!!
```

The problem is the variables I set in the top level view do not get passed to the embedded view. How could I make that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm not exactly answering your question, but here's my super-simple hand-grown template system. It supports what you're trying to do, although the interface is different.

```
// Usage
$main = new SimpleTemplate("templating/html.php");
$main->extract($someObject);
$main->extract($someArray);
$main->name = "my name";
$subTemplate = new SimpleTemplate("templating/another.php");
$subTemplate->parent($main);
$main->placeholderForAnotherTemplate = $subTemplate->run();
echo $main; // or $main->run(); 

// html.php
<html><body><h1>Title <?= $name ?></h1><p><?= $placeHolderForAnotherTemplate ?></p></body></html>

    <?php
// SimpleTemplate.php
function object_to_array($object)
{
    $array = array();
    foreach($object as $property => $value)
    {
        $array[$property] = $value;
    }

    return $array;
}

class SimpleTemplate
{
    public $source;
    public $path;
    public $result;
    public $parent;

    public function SimpleTemplate($path=false, $source=false)
    {
        $this->source = array();
        $this->extract($source);
        $this->path($path);
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->run();
    }

    public function extract($source)
    {
        if ($source)
        {
            foreach ($source as $property => $value)
            {
                $this->source[$property] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    public function parent($parent)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;
    }

    public function path($path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->source[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        return isset($this->source[$name]) ? $this->source[$name] : "";
    }

    public function mergeSource()
    {
        if (isset($this->parent))
            return array_merge($this->parent->mergeSource(), $this->source);
        else
            return $this->source;
    }

    public function run()
    {
        ob_start();
        extract ($this->mergeSource());
        include $this->path;
        $this->result = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $this->result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This made me realize that even in big frameworks, you're supposed to render the view in your controller and then just pass the rendered view in a variable to the top level view. I was trying to render the view inside another view.

Answer (score 0):

well, you create a new instance of the class, so there are no variables defined in the embedded template. you should try to copy the object, rather than creating a new one.

edit: I'm talking about the factory method

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that your views have no direct knowledge of each other.  By calling this:

```
<?=View::factory('embed')->output()?>
```

in your "parent" view, you create and output a template that has no knowledge of the fact that it is inside another template.

There are two approaches I could recommend here.

**#1 - Associate your templates.**

By making your embedded templates "children" of a parent template, you could allow them to have access to the parent's variables at `output()` time.  I utilize this approach in a View system I built.  It goes something like this:

```
$pView = new View_Parent_Class();
$cView = new View_Child_Class();
$pView->addView($cView);
```

At `$pview->render()` time, the child view is easily given access to the parent's variables.

This method might require a lot of refactoring for you, so I'll leave out the dirty details, and go into the second approach.

**#2 - Pass the parent variables**

This would probably be the easiest method to implement given the approach you've taken so far.  Add an optional parameter to your output method, and rewrite it slightly, like this:

```
public function output($extra_vars = null)
{
    if (count($this->_vars))
        extract($this->_vars,  EXTR_REFS);
    if (is_array($extra_vars)) extract($extra_vars, EXTR_REFS);
    require($this->_file);
    exit;
}
```

If you add a simple getter method as well:

```
public function get_vars()
{
    return $this->_vars;
}
```

Then you can embed your files with what is effectively read-access to the parent's variables:

```
<?=View::factory('embed')->output($this->get_vars())?>
```

`$this` will be a reference to the current template, ie. the parent.  Note that you can have variable name collisions via this method because of the two `extract` calls.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your $_vars property static, not particularly elegant, but would work for what you are trying to achieve.

On a side note... your array_merge() in the set() function is wrong, swap your 2 variables around.

Comment: How could it be wrong? It merges 2 arrays together. That's like saying 2+3 != 3+2

Comment: Shouldn't the vars passed to the set() function overwrite the old ones? At the moment, if you call $view->set(array('title' => 'Title1'))->set(array('title' => 'Title2'))->output(); // Title will be Title1